# Как сделать двухязычный сайт в вордпрессе?

Tags: wordpress

Я создал сайт на вордпрессе: основной язык русский. Хочу добавить таджикский язык на сайте, но не знаю как сделать... помогите пожалуйста!!!!!

Comment: Попробуйте поискать плагины переводов/локализации в базе плагинов Вордпресс https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=translate

Answer (score 2):

Есть один "дедовский способ": делаешь поддомен или подпапку, в которую переносишь весь движок с базой данных (делаешь копию сайта), а потом садишься и все вручную переводишь.

Comment: спасибо большое всем....

Answer (score 0):

Как и любая задача, которая встречается часто, задача создать мультиязычный сайт на wordpresss имеет готовые решения.

1. Плагин [WPML](https://wpml.org/ru/) - наверно лучшее решение, но платный.
2. Бесплатный аналог плагин [Polylang](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/), со своей задачей справляется отлично.